# Understanding the manipulation of integers in the given function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, integer

Being new to python, I'm starting to ask more and more questions.  A lot of the time is understanding trying to understand 'complicated' lines of code that seem to do a lot in a single line.  This has given me an better appreciations for Python as I build my own knowledge in the subject.

**Background**:

I've come across of a function that reverses/manipulates numbers but its difficult to understand what's happening in the IF/Else Statement.  I use a few tools to better understand these statements including [PythonTutor](https://pythontutor.com) that gives me a step by step visual of what's happening in code. I've added the code right below this and the screen shots below that are from Python Tutor.

```
def reverse(x):
    a = str(x)
    
    if a[0] == '-':
        return int('-'+a[:0:-1])
    else:
        return int(a[::-1])
    
print(reverse(-387))
print(reverse(712))
```

**Context**:

In this screen shot below, I'm having a hard time understanding what's happening in `[:0:-1]`.  I understand that if there's a negative in the integer, then continue w/ this statement but why would it be starting at the `:0` in this statement?  Aren't we trying to take the last int which is `-1` and put it to the beginning?

My question is shouldn't it be `[:-1:0]` since we want to capture the last int and place it first?

[image]

I have the same type of question, which is confusing me, related the `Else` portion of the IF statement (below).  The portion `[::-1]` shows that there's no need to capture the `0` in it, Why is this?  Don't we still need the `0` index because we still need to reverse a positive integer, correct?

[image]

I guess this can be a 2-part question.  Would love to understand this better and if there's a version of this that may not been a IF/Else Statement, that may also help me understand this better.

Comment: You don't seem to understand Python ranges.  When used as a slice index, the general form is `[start:end:step]`.  The sequence begins at `start`, and stops *before* `end` (i.e., `end` is excluded`).  The `step` tells it how much to advance the index each time.  If `start` is absent, it is `0` (for a positive `step`) or `len(seq) - 1` for a negative `step`.   If `end` is absent, it is `len(seq)` (for a positive `step`) or the position before `0` (like `-1`, but without the special interpretation for negative values) (for a negative step).

Comment: So `[::-1]` reverses the *entire* sequence.  `[:0:-1]` skips the first item and reverses the rest.  Your proposed `[:-1:0]` is invalid, since a `step` value of `0` would just repeat infinitely.  And indeed, if you attempt a step size of `0`, you will receive the appropriate error.

Comment: The above link contains a good answer to this duplicate question.

Comment: Seems to me a duplicate question - as @TomKarzes pointed out.

Comment: @WilliamZebrowski - 1) avoid using the built-in method `reverse`  (changed to my_reverse, eg);  2) include the code next time, not the image.